# generar un array String aleatorio con RANDOM?

Tags: java, array, string, netbeans, random

Quiero imprimir un array random. no pueden reptirse datos.

```
String[] Fruta={manzana,pera,platano,pera,fresa};
 Random r= new Random();
int e = r.nextInt(Fruta.length);
```

Comment: Como lo tienes no se repetirian los datos. Te sugiero explicar que deseas realizar

Answer (score 0):

Olvidaste incluir los nombres de las frutas entre comillas para se guarden como `String`.

Para mostrar el resultado utiliza un `System.out.print()` que imprima el elemento en la posición aleatoria.

```
import java.util.Random;

class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random r = new Random();

    String[] Fruta = {"manzana","pera","platano","pera","fresa"};

    int e = r.nextInt(Fruta.length);

    System.out.println("Una fruta al azar: " + Fruta[e]);
  }
}
```